# How to get last insert ID of drupal_write_record

Tags: database

I need to get the last inserted id in drupal 7. I am using

```
drupal_write_record('user_log', $log)
```

How we can get the last_instered_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `{user_log}` table has a PRIMARY KEY with it, or something else serial, then it should be set in in the array you passed to it.  In your case, it would be something like

```
$last_log_id = $log['log_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not dependent on drupal_write_record you can use *db_insert* and/or *db_update* instead. The execute() method of the query objects returns the current id.